# Switch/Load new detailpage in Xamarin via code

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

How do I load/switch between pages like you would with the side menu of a Masterdetailpage via code?

[image: video]

If you click on a page name on the side menu, you will go to that page, while keeping the menu button on the new page. How do you do this via code?

**MainPage.xaml (which is the home page)**

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TimeToSport;assembly=TimeToSport"
              xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:TimeToSport.Views.Main"
              xmlns:local2="clr-namespace:TimeToSport.Views"
              x:Class="TimeToSport.Views.Main.MainPage">
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <local1:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage" />
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <local2:ItemsPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

**MasterPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TimeToSport.Views"
             xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:TimeToSport.Views"
             x:Class="TimeToSport.Views.Main.MasterPage"
             Padding="0,40,0,0"
             Icon="hamburger.png"
             Title="Personal Organiser">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" x:FieldModifier="public">
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:MasterPageItem}">
                    <local1:MasterPageItem Title="Home" IconSource="contacts.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:ItemsPage}" />
                    <local1:MasterPageItem Title="Slaap" IconSource="todo.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:SlaapPage}" />
                    <local1:MasterPageItem Title="Voeding" IconSource="reminders.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:VoedingPage}" />
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="5,10">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I know very little about the masterdetailpage, detailpage etc...

If you go to "Slaap" page via code like:

```
Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SlaapPage());
```

you won't have the menu button on the top-left corner, but I want it to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Detail` page to do so & your current page should be inherit from `MasterDetailPage`

```
public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Detail = new NavigationPage(new HomePage());
        IsPresented = false; //This is to hide side page after pushing new page 

    }
}
```

If you do like above `Detail = new..` than it not going to show you back button arrow on top left. 
If you want back arrow in `Actionbar` do like this

```
Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
```

If you want to do it from other pages do like this

```
public void SlaapClicked()
{ 
 Navigation.PushAsync(new SlaapPage());
}
```

On SlaapPage hide the `Navigationbar`

```
public SlaapPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
}
```

If you are moving from other `TabbedPage` do like this

```
private void SlaapPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this.Navigation.PushAsync(new SlaapPage());// not showing back button
    //(App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail=new NavigationPage(new SlaapPage()); //showing full screen page
    (App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new SlaapPage()); //working like google play store app, In SlaapPage page SetHasNavigationBar should be false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how do I do this from another page? I have a button with the following function

 `void Slaap_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
            mainPage.SlaapClicked();
        }` at ItemsPage.cs (itemspage = homepage). In MainPage.cs I have this code 
`public void SlaapClicked()
        {
            Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new SlaapPage());
        }` However, this doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to push pages from other pages for those you should use `Navigation.PushAsync` only because already you have detail container open no need to use `Detail` from other pages. Check my edits.

Comment: `(App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail=new NavigationPage(new SlaapPage());` did what I wanted. When I click on a button, it's showing the slaap page with the menu button at the top-left corner. Thanks!